# How to save the data of the inputs generated by *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor

So, I'm working with Angular 5 and I have two arrays with data extracted from a database:

```
["Reports", "UI"]
```

and

```
0: {ranges: "Low", ph: 0, days: 0}
1: {ranges: "Mediu,", ph: 0, days: 0}
2: {ranges: "High", ph: 0, days: 0}
```

I´m showing the second array for each element inside the first array. After that I have an input and also repeat it as i did with the second array

```html
    ...
    <tbody *ngFor="let i of paramsData; let y = index"> <---Repeat the data from first array
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of times; let x = index"> <---Repeat the data from second array in each element in the first array
        <tr>
          <td [attr.rowspan]="times.length" *ngIf="x == 0">{{i}}</td>
          <td>{{data.ranges}}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name='weight'>
          </td>
          <td>{{data.ph}}</td>
          <td>{{data.days}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
    ...
```

QUESTION: How can I get the values introduced in the inputs generated automatically by the `*ngFor`? I cannot assign a value inside a `formControlName` because all the inputs will have the same name and only will save one value.

Also, I cannot use the `[(ngModel)]="someArray[x]"` to stores the values in an array because it only will save the values of the first iteration on the second `ngFor`.

Am I losing something? Is there an option to do that?

**-- EDIT --**

Link to StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ux4cqv

---

**Screenshot of the table**

[image: My table looks like this]

Comment: if you add your code in stackblitz.com it will easy to help you!

Comment: Have you considered formArrayName? https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName

Comment: @Chellappan This is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ux4cqv

Comment: @pixelbits Not yet. How can i do it with that?

Comment: You could transform the data to match what you want displayed [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwiikk?file=src/app/app.component.html).  `model = this.params.map(param => ({param: param, times: this.ranges.map(time => Object.assign({}, time))}))` and bind the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-andacc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You could implement forms as a two-dimensional-array:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  params = ["Reports", "UI"];
  ranges = [
    {ranges: "Low", ph: 0, days: 0},
    {ranges: "Medium,", ph: 0, days: 0},
    {ranges: "High", ph: 0, days: 0}
  ]
  constructor() {
    var paramsArray = new FormArray([]);
    this.params.forEach(t=> {
      var rangeArray = new FormArray([]);
      paramsArray.push(rangeArray);
      this.ranges.forEach(t=> {
        rangeArray.push(new FormControl(''))
      });
    });

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      "values": paramsArray
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
<table border="1" formArrayName="values">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Param. de Estimación</th>
            <th>Complejidad</th>
            <th>Peso</th>
            <th>Product. Hora</th>
            <th>Esf. en Dias</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let i of params; index as y" [formArrayName]="y">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of ranges; index as x">
            <tr>
                <td [attr.rowspan]="ranges.length" *ngIf="x == 0">{{i}}</td>
                <td>{{data.ranges}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" [formControlName]="x" placeholder="Weight" name='weight'>
                </td>
                <td>{{data.ph}}</td>
                <td>{{data.days}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
        <button type="submit" *ngIf="y==1">Pto. de Referencia</button>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The form values are saved to a "values" two-dimensional array, which you can get from calling `formGroup.value`:

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. This is working smoothly and perfectly. You save my day and my week. Thank you. NOTE: I have to change the `var` definition to `let`. To access to the values its necessary write this: `formGroup.value.values`